# Datasource on MasterPage calling Parameter on Child Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, datasource

I'm using a RadPanelBar to call a asp datasource on my masterpage

```
<telerik:RadPanelBar ID="NavigationPanelBar" runat="server" DataSourceID="ViewUserPageNavigation"
            Skin="Web20" Width="100%" AllowCollapseAllItems="true" DataTextField="PageDescription"
            DataFieldID="CategoryId" DataFieldParentID="ParentId" DataNavigateUrlField="PageURL"
            CssClass="NavContainer">
        </telerik:RadPanelBar>

<data:ViewUserPageNavigationDataSource runat="server" ID="ViewUserPageNavigation"
    SelectMethod="GetPaged">
    <Parameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="WhereClause" ControlID="__Page" PropertyName="ViewUserPageNavigationWhereClause"
            Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="OrderBy" ControlID="__Page" PropertyName="ViewUserPageNavigationOrderBy"
            Type="String" />
    </Parameters>
</data:ViewUserPageNavigationDataSource>
```

On my masterpage behind code i have both of those parameters

```
public String ViewUserPageNavigationWhereClause
{

    get
    {
        String where = "UserId = " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "";
        return where;
    }


}

public String ViewUserPageNavigationOrderBy
{
    get
    {

        String orderBy = "tblpages.PageDescription";
        return orderBy;
    }

}
```

However I get the error that my childpage does not contain ViewUserPageNavigationWhereClause

DataBinding: 'ASP.secure_index_aspx' does not contain a property with the name 'ViewUserPageNavigationWhereClause'.

`secure_index_aspx` is my child page `masterpage.Masterpage` is my master

this one loses me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood the question a little, so I'm re-writing my answer:

As far as I'm aware you cannot access the master page's datasource from a child page.  Is there a specific reason that the datasrouce is on the masterpage instead of the child page?

An alternative to this setup (if you're just looking for re-usability), is to create a class that inherits from the page object and add your datasource controls and method to that class.  Make all of the pages in your site inherit from your new class instead of the page object.

EDIT: After our discussion in the comments below, it appears that the problem is that you are accidentally accessing the __page object instead of the controls on the masterpage.

If you are trying to access the properties in the code-behind instead of controls on the page, try using "this" instead of __page.  If that doesn't work, you should maybe rethink your strategy.  You could also put those properties into a session variable and use session parameters instead.

Comment: Rephistorch - what i'm saying is the masterpage data source is trying to access parameters on the child page instead of the masterepage

Comment: Is the example code above correct?  It looks like you created those properties on the masterpage instead of the child page.

Comment: I did create those on the masterpage, but when the page loads, it's looking for them on the child page, i believe thats true becuase the controlId is __Page, how do you target the masterpage instead of the child page?

Comment: The masterpage datasource is looking for those ControlParameter Parameters on the child page instead of the Parent Page

Comment: So you do have controls exactly called "ViewUserPageNavigationWhereClause", and "ViewUserPageNavigationOrderBy" on the child page?

Comment: I would also like to add that you should check the control's accessibility level.  Make sure that it's declared as "public" rather than "protected" (which I believe is the default).

Comment: Rephistorch i'm not answering this question again for sake...  I do not have that control on the child page!! I do not want it on the child page!  I want it one the masterpage!  I have it on the master page. The problem is the data source is trying to access it on the child page and not the master page

Comment: Oh? We have apparently had a communication error.  If the control is on the masterpage, just list the name of the control, and the property to be access.  You shouldn't be calling the "__page" control at all in this scenario.

Comment: A session variable may yet be a viable option in that case.